# Phoenix 1.3 + Bootstrap 4 + webpack 2 + fontawesome sass

Tags: font-awesome, phoenix-framework, webpack-2, bootstrap-4

I'm using Phoenix Elixir framework and I decided to replace brunch with Webpack2 plus adding bootstrap alpha 6 for the frontend framework, and according to the migration section, they've get ridden of the glyphicons.
So I decided to integrate with `fontawesome` as a sass loader:
So for that purpose I reviewed the following npm package:
`font-awesome-sass-loader` and followed the instructions in their website.

However, when trying to use the fa classes, the icon is not being displayed.
Strangely enough when looking at the `app.js` generated file, I don't see any trace of content related to `fontawesome`, what am I missing?

Here is my `webpack.config.js`:

```
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: ['bootstrap-loader' ,'./web/static/js/app.js'],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'priv/static/dist'),
    filename: 'app.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ from: './web/static/assets', to: path.resolve('./priv/static/') }]),
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
        filename: 'app.css',
        allChunks : true
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery",
        "window.jQuery": "jquery",
        Tether: "tether",
        "window.Tether": "tether",
        Alert: "exports-loader?Alert!bootstrap/js/dist/alert",
        Button: "exports-loader?Button!bootstrap/js/dist/button",
        Carousel: "exports-loader?Carousel!bootstrap/js/dist/carousel",
        Collapse: "exports-loader?Collapse!bootstrap/js/dist/collapse",
        Dropdown: "exports-loader?Dropdown!bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown",
        Modal: "exports-loader?Modal!bootstrap/js/dist/modal",
        Popover: "exports-loader?Popover!bootstrap/js/dist/popover",
        Scrollspy: "exports-loader?Scrollspy!bootstrap/js/dist/scrollspy",
        Tab: "exports-loader?Tab!bootstrap/js/dist/tab",
        Tooltip: "exports-loader?Tooltip!bootstrap/js/dist/tooltip",
        Util: "exports-loader?Util!bootstrap/js/dist/util",
    })
],
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: [{
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              options: {
                presets: ['env', 'es2015']
              }
            }]

        },
        { test: /bootstrap[\/\\]dist[\/\\]js[\/\\]umd[\/\\]/, use: 'imports-loader?jQuery=jquery' },
        {
            test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'url-loader',
                    options: {
                        limit: 10000,
                        mimetype: 'application/font-woff'
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
            use: [
                { loader: 'file-loader' }
            ]
        }
    ]
  }
};
```

Here is my `app.js` file:

```
import "phoenix_html"
import "font-awesome-sass-loader";
```

Here is my `index.html.eex` file:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h1><i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i> App</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
  </div>
</div>
```

And my `package.json`:

```
{
  "repository": {},
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "deploy": "node_modules/.bin/webpack -p",
    "watch": "node_modules/.bin/webpack --watch-stdin --progress --color",
    "postinstall": "sh ./post-install.sh"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "phoenix": "file:deps/phoenix",
    "phoenix_html": "file:deps/phoenix_html"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.5.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "bootstrap": "v4.0.0-alpha.6",
    "bootstrap-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.2",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "font-awesome-sass-loader": "^2.0.1",
    "imports-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.5",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^2.0.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.5",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "webpack": "^2.6.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Why replace brunch? Could you meet your goal of using Bootstrap4 without making the change?

Comment: Bootstrap 4 works great, the issue I have is with the icon fonts, since it has been removed from the core library. When I add it manually, then I have the issue. I really like webpack over brunch.